# Arrangement Div tags like this?

Tags: css, html

I'm gonna create two `div` tags with `CSS` that appear in the page like below :

[alt text http://xs.to/image-5E61_4B88C82D.jpg](http://xs.to/image-5E61_4B88C82D.jpg)

Would you please guide me, how I should write the CSS codes?
Thanks.

Comment: @Mohammad: i have updated my answer for two divs, please check out the demo link, hope that helps thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Fixed For Two DIVs**

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/afuhe3/3) :)**

Please see the source code...

Comment: Thanks. Can't we create it just with two `Div` tags? Isn't it possible?

Comment: @Sarfraz, you're still using 3 divs in your answer. I believe the questioner needs to do it with 2 divs

Comment: @Naeem Sarfraz: i did not spot that in the question. you are right, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

try  this

```
 #div-01
    {
      position :absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      height:600px;
      width:800px;
      background-color:gray;
    }   

    #div-02
    {
      position :absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:200px;
      height:500px;
      width:400px;
      background-color:yellow;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this

```
#div-01 
{ 
  z-index:1;
  height:300px; 
  width:800px; 
  background-color:gray; 
}    

#div-02 
{ 
  z-index:2;
  height:500px; 
  width:400px; 
  background-color:yellow; 
} 

<div id="div-01">
    <div id="div-02"></div>
</div>
```